# How to view and download pdf in Flash and AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, pdf, flash-cs5

I'm creating a flash website and I want to implement a pdf file viewer (download file button) so that when a user clicks the button, the person can view the pdf file in a browser, but im not sure how to do that in Actionscript 3.0, any simple code on how to do this?

Patrick

Comment: Well, you can `navigateToURL` to the location of the pdf. If the browser has a pdf reader plugin, it'll open in-browser. If not, it'll ask to save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [flexpaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/default.jsp)? It is free for open source projects too.

Comment: +1. FlexPaper is AWESOME, and I'd used some of his code earlier when I was making a flipbook. He didn't have the pdf reader then, so I used [pdf2swf from swftools](http://www.swftools.org/) to convert the pdf into a swf and then display the swf